# Why is "länger" used here?

Tags: word-usage

Here is a random sample of [sentences from DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%40l%C3%A4ngerem&corpus=kern&format=full&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&p=4&sort=date_desc&limit=10) that seem to me to use "länger" not in a comparative sense:

> Rußland ist der PfP **nach längerem Zögern** im Mai diesen Jahres beigetreten.

> **Seit längerem** bekam ihm die zweite Tasse nicht.

> Jerusalem stimmte **nach längerem Zögern** -und dem Vernehmen nach unter amerikanischem und russischem Druck - der Stationierung einer UN-Beobachtertruppe zu, deren Mitglieder über Handfeuerwaffen verfügten und die nach Hebron, in den Gaza-Streifen und in das Gebiet um Jericho entsandt werde.

And here is a sentence from a recent Tatort dialog:

> Sie ist **nach längerem Leiden** vor 10 Jahren gestorben.

Why do they not use "lang"? And would it be in error to use "lang" in these instead?  I note that the same expressions appear with either the adjectives or with the comparatives, and wonder if, to a native speaker, there is a difference in meaning between the two.

Comment: Maybe. Please note my edit.

Comment: I think, "lang" means really long while "länger" in this context means "quite long". In some cases you might translate it with "longish", as far as I understand with my limited knowledge of the English language.